# Vertical alignment of text around a symbol in table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, align

Is there a way to organize the vertical alignment in table around a particular symbol. For example in the below code

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{1}{c}}
    a = b + c \\
    a + b = c + d \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{16 constants used for BLAKE-256}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

A sample table would look like

```
  a = b + c
a + b = c + d
```

However, I would like the output to center align around equals sign. Something like below.

```
    a = b + c
a + b = c + d
```

Is something like this possible in latex?

Answer (score 2):

Is there are reason you aren't using `align*`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{align*}
    a & = b + c \\
    a + b & = c + d
  \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{16 constants used for BLAKE-256}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, the correct answer *is* with `align*`; the present one has several glitches. For example it doesn't use math mode and the spacing is terrible.

Comment: @egreg I asked the OP if there is a reason why he isn't using align.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that worked.

Well, I was not aware of the align package. I kept Google searching for vertical table alignment, rather than alignment.

Comment: There are a few nontrivial TeX crimes committed here :)

Comment: No, I am using the align* just like you highlighted in your code above. That enabled me to get rid of the redundant equation numbers that appear at the far right.

Comment: -1, switching from tabular to align* isn't exactly a small change. E.g. with multiple rows (of which one should be aligned in this way), alternating row colors, it's not a feasible alternative.

Comment: @stefan I believe that is the posters call if they want to make the change.  Additionally, align is more suitable for equations then tabular.

Comment: @dustin Ever heard of multiple columns, row colors, or any other fancy table stuff? Stackexchange is a platform not to solve the posters problem only. There is a reason for that it is not deleted after an answer is found and the poster is happy. Others should be able to use the answer as well, even in a slightly different context. That's impossible with these crappy "do something completely different instead" answers.

Comment: @stefan you need to check your attitude and go else where if you think the answers on this site are crappy. I bet you wouldn't run your mouth like that if it wasn't over the internet.

Comment: @dustin Not at all. I say the same thing "offline" about tex / latex / tex.stackexchange.com. It's a weird philosophy of "Nevermind what others may want to do. You can do it that other way. You're doing it wrong."